# Problem with partialPlot for randomForest in R

Tags: r

I would like to ask a question about partialPlot in R if anyone knows. So I fitted a randomForest Model using the command:
`forest_model <- randomForest(price ~., data = new_data, xtest = testCov,ytest = testResponse, subset = train_ind, ntree = 70, importance = TRUE, mtry = 1)`

And then I was trying to have the partialPlot but here is what the error said:
*Error in partialPlot.randomForest(forest_model_op, as.data.frame(train_data),  :
The randomForest object must contain the forest.*

The code I used is `partialPlot(forest_model_op, new_data, x.var = "fuel")` and I don't know why it said there is no forest.

Thanks if anyone could help with it!

Comment: You called your model `forest_model`, not `forest_model_op`

Comment: `forest_model_op` is the second model I created and I did call the second one for my partial plot. Sorry for the confusion here but I still can't figure out what might be the problem.